# Mass image download script in PHP

Tags: php, download

I need a .php script that will download a lot of images from another site. The images are thumbs - each has about 20KB size.
I have worked on my own script, but sadly it just lags my server and nearly kills it forcing me to restart it.

There are about 100 pictures or more per execution, .jpg files, ~20KB / file.

My script:

```
$count = 0;
foreach ($files as $file) {
$count++;
$url = $file;
$dl_place = '/home/lulz/'.$count.'.jpg';

$ch = curl_init($dl);
$fp = fopen($path, 'wb');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
}
```

As you see I am using curl, but I am willing to use anything if it just works better than it is now.

Comment: -1 Even if it is just for the lulz it still appears that you are stealing these images and being a nuicance to the owner of the other server.

Comment: @Blender obviously, the OP is asking for some kind of optimization.

Comment: Noooo idea why this post is getting downvotes.  You have no idea what his intentions are here.  There may be legit reasons for this.  It's not as if he came out and said, "I want to steal every image on the web and hog bandwidth".  Sure, the possibility of being a pest is there, but that is the case with most code.

Comment: You don't have to create a new curl each time. You can re-use the same curl handle and just change the url each time.

Comment: 100 x 20KB is hardly bandwidth hogging anyway

Comment: @Brad This one is pretty obvious in my eyes. Btw: @user606346 : Are these Thumbs that you are "legitimately mass-downloading" suitable for viewing by my children? :-)

Comment: I am working on a search engine for a niche site. It hurts to read most of these comments on here. This script will run once a day. Of course they are @Simen S

Comment: @Simen S This is what you except from php download scripts?? Oh god. :O

Comment: @user606346 I don't think I was the only one to think so.

Comment: @Simen S, you should be voting on questions based on how useful it is.  Comment away, but don't downvote the question.  Again, you don't know his intentions with any certainty either way, and in most cases, that intent shouldn't be relevant to the vote.  At least, not in my opinion, based on what I read on meta.

Comment: @Brad OK. I get it. @User606346 could you add a tiny edit to your question? My downvote is locked in and irreversible unless you the q is edited.

Comment: @User606346. Reversed. At least I commented to explain my initial downvote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chances are, what is slowing down is the time it takes to set up all of these requests.  You should consider [Parallel cURL](http://www.codediesel.com/php/parallel-curl-execution/) to download multiple at a time.  Source code:  https://github.com/petewarden/ParallelCurl/blob/master/parallelcurl.php

```
$pc->startRequest('http://www.whatever.com/someimage.jpg', 'your_callback_function');
```

I have also found that with library, you can use anonymous functions instead of the name of a function in your callback.  I use this to call another function with an ID number, for example.

```
$requestid=37;
$pc->startRequest(
    $url, 
    function($content, $url, $ch, $search) use $requestid {
        yourRealCallback($content, $url, $ch, $search, $requestid);
    }
);
```

This utilizes an anonymous function with closure so that if you are searching a DB of URLs, you can get the resulting ID (that you specify in a for loop or something... hard-coded to '37' here for demonstration).

Comment: Okay, I am implementing this. But I have one question: How can I set the destination of the file (where it will be saved)?

Comment: @user606346, the downloaded data will appear in $content in your callback function.  You will need to handle it there.  Alternatively, you can set `CURLOPT_FILE` and pass a file handle that you opened with `fopen()`.  Be sure to set those options each time you download a file then, or you will be overwriting the same file.  (That's one of the reasons it is probably just easier to handle it with $content, especially since you expect your data to be relatively small.)