# How to download all images from a website?

Tags: php, curl

I want to download multiple images from the following website: 
www.bbc.co.uk
I want to do it by using PHP cURL, can someone help lead me in the right direction?

It would be nice to download all the images in one shot, but if someone can help me download maybe download just 1 or a bunch that would be great!

Edit: it would be a good idea to show what I have tried:

```
<?php
$image_url = "www.bbc.co.uk";
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 0;
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $image_url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);

// Getting binary data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);

$image = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// output to browser
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
print $image;
?>
```

For some reason it is not working. It is to be noted I am an absolute amatuer at PHP and programming in general.

Comment: Consider `wget`, it's pretty much the best tool for pulling images off a website.

Comment: This is for a university assignment. I'm not sure if i am allowed to use wget

Comment: "I'm not sure if I am allowed to use wget" - You've been set a problem. Assigned to solve it. Why are you restricted into what tools you are allowed to use to solve such problem?

Comment: When you do the script above you dont get the images. The images come from a json webservice: http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/4.2.6/data/en_GB/champion.json

Comment: Its in the requirement, its a bit crappy, I know.

Comment: The script you posted just fetches a single images and shows it; by the way people in SO won't code for you (even because it's an assignment for you, and you're supposed to learn something out of it :)).

I can give you some hints: you have to set up some cycle to fetch all the images and save them to disk. The JSON posted in the comments by @PedroEstrada is a good start. Start studying here: www.php.net/json‎

Comment: this is my last help http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/#http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/4.2.6/data/en_GB/champion.json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above code you pasted isn't doing what you think it is.

```
$image = curl_exec($ch);
```

The `$image` variable doesn't contain any image, it actually contains the entire HTML of that webpage as a string.

If you replace

```
// output to browser
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
print $image;
```

with:

```
var_dump($image);
```

You will see the html.

Something like this:

[image: curl output]

Try to find the actual champion image source and parse it accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You just need the whole /Air/assets/images/champions folder right?

Nothing easier when you use FireFox and a Download plugin like "Download Them All", open the FTP folder (Eambo's link) where the champions' pictures are located, right clic, select the plug-in.
It's gonna list all the files, select them all or select those you need and start the download.

Also, if you own that game you can take a look in this path:

```
\League of Legends\rads\projects\lol_air_client\releases\<newest-version>\deploy\assets\images\champions
```

Since you will probably use that in your university, [CHECK THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5572386/mass-image-download-script-in-php) and I hope you will find a solution.

Comment: I don't think he has it installed on his university PC :) He needs to download images from the webpage.

Comment: I just added one more line of text into my answer.

Comment: This is correct. The idea is for me to create a program that downloads the images. Not download a program that downloads the images, is that what you suggested? If it is then sorry thats not the idea :).

Comment: @user3306183 check the link I posted in my answer, I guess that could help you.

Comment: @Hoh thanks for that! Now i just have to find a way to implent + figure what the heck is going on there haha. Thank you.